# I wonder whether MATLAB is Turing complete (computationally universal)?

Tags: matlab

I wonder whether MATLAB is [Turing complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness) (= computationally universal, i.e. "if it can be used to simulate any single-taped Turing machine")?

Comment: I reworded my question to convey what I really meant.

Comment: Why not implement a Turing machine in Matlab to prove it for yourself?

Comment: Note that a true Turing machine requires an infinite tape, so I think, strictly speaking, any language can only be "Turing complete" as long as we assume an arbitrarily large amount of memory.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Being Turing complete is really a pretty low bar for real-world languages.  According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness) (emphasis mine):

> To show that something is Turing complete, it is enough to show that
>   it can be used to simulate some Turing complete system. For example,
>   an imperative language is Turing complete if it has **conditional**
>   **branching** (e.g., "if" and "goto" statements, or a "branch if zero"
>   instruction. See OISC) and the **ability to change arbitrary memory**
>   **locations** (e.g., the ability to maintain an arbitrary number of
>   variables). Since this is almost always the case, most if not all
>   imperative languages are Turing complete if we ignore any limitations
>   of finite memory.

Beyond that, MATLAB has many of the features you would expect from a relatively modern [3GL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third-generation_programming_language)/[4GL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth-generation_programming_language).  It is complete with a VM, I/O, user interface constructs, mathematical operators (obviously), datatypes, user-defined-functions, etc.  You can even deliver Matlab programs outside the Matlab environment.

Note that whether or not it's a **good** language is an entirely different question.

Comment: And u can also use matlab libs outside Matlab

Comment: but would it also be possible to write a matlab "compiler" entirely in matlab, or rewrite matlab itself in matlab respectively?

Comment: @karsten of course.  I can't imagine such a thing being very practical, but I see no reason why it wouldn't be possible.

Comment: Would anyone where I could find a proof that Matlab is indeed Turing complete?

Comment: @calys I've updated my answer to address this, albeit not a formal proof.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, a [high-level programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-level_programming_language).

Answer (score 3):

I assume you distinguish between programming languages and scripting languages, and because of the nature of MATLAB it appears like a scripting language? If this is the case, your opinion might depend on what you consider a programming language.

I believe MATLAB is Turing-complete and has a reasonably strict and usable syntax, so I'd call it a programming language. At the same time though, csh is probably turing-complete, but it's so dramatically odd to program in that I'd call it a scripting language.

Comment: The "programming vs. scripting" argument might get even more complicated for MATLAB since it draws distinctions between "scripts" and "m-files" (i.e. "functions").

Comment: csh = c shell, one of the shell scripting languages typically found on  linux, unix, bsd, etc.

Comment: "reasonably strict syntax" could someone point me to a formal definition of the syntax (EBNF or something)?